# Redux-auto: action chaining vs index reducer

Tags: javascript, redux, chaining, redux-middleware

Can anyone tell me what the difference between using [chain](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#chaining-action-together) on a reducer function and doing  work in the main [index reducer](https://github.com/codemeasandwich/redux-auto#index-files) function in [redux-auto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-auto)

I want to save an error,

A) store/chat/send.js

```
import actions from 'redux-auto'

//...

 function rejected(chat, payload, error){
  return chat;
} onError.chain = (c, p, error) => actions.logger.save(error)

//...
```

or

B) store/logger/index.js

```
import actions from 'redux-auto'
import save from './save'

export default function (errorsLog = [], action)
{
   if(action.type == actions.chat.send.rejected){
      return save(errorsLog,action.payload)
   }
   return errorsLog
}
```

**They both work**

My questions:

1. I don't know what would be better. What is the difference?
2. Why would I use one over the other?
3. Also, can't I just call the action `logger.save(...)` inside the
   `rejected`. Why does this `chain` feature exist?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Using the chain(OnError) will fire the action AFTER the source(rejected) reducer has completed. creating a new call across you store.

B) You are changing the state in the source reducer call

Your qustions:

1,2) Using chaining will make you code more readable as the next function is collocated with the source reducer, but but having it in the index group all action that will happen to that part of the store.

3) Calling an action function directly within a reducer function. Is an anti-pattern. This is dispatching an action in the middle of a dispatched action. The reducer will be operating on inconsistent data.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main Redux point is predictability. We should use as more `pure` functions as possible. The reducer must not have any side-effects at all.

Recently I've worked on the same feature - error (user action, etc) logging. I think all of this actions are `side-effects`. They have no profit for user and can't be a part of main business logic.

That's why I use `custom middleware` to capture all actions I need to log. The action which I need to log I've marked with some `meta-prop` (ex. `{log: 'errorLog'}`) and in the middleware I checked every action. If it has a `log` prop then I make some logger magic.

Finally I've got clearly understandable code where all of logging side-effects incapsulated in middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am trying to understand the mechanisms of this framework. Do you have any thoughts on chaining in redux-auto? As it seem to be a new approach.

Comment: I didn't use this library. I want to have a full control of my application, but `redux-auto` (as it is written in docs) reduces boilerplate by hiding some part of realisation. Injecting my action-creators to `action` object is kind of *black magic* for me. But it is only my opinion.